# Flutter - Future handling

Tags: flutter, asynchronous, async-await

i have two functions, and the idea is that the 1 need to be executed first

```
Future<bool> _getProducts() async {
   father.Reload().then((value){//it will do a http request and refresh in the other screen, this other screen will bring data to the actual screen later
     if(value != null && value is bool && value){
       print("1 finished");
       return Future.value(true);
     }
     return Future.value(true);
   });
   return Future.value(false);
 }

 Future Reload() async {
    await _getProducts().then((){
      print("2 finished");
    });
 }
```

i can't understand why, but it always prints 2 finished before 1 finished, i already tried with whencomplete, without await, and other possibilities but i still can't figure it out

Comment: you need to use `await` before `father.Reload()`

Comment: this worked, thank you so much